# couldn't access internet resource even if successfully connect to pptp vpn

Tags: vpn, pptp

I hire host which locate Tokyo as my vps server, and I follow this article to install pptp server

[article about install pptp from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp)

and my vps ip >>> `107.191.60.187`

in addtion, I install ufw and allow pptpd's port by this way

```
ufw allow 1723
ufw disable && ufw enable
```

but in fact I can't access internet resource even if I could successfully connect my pptpd program on vps.

I really don't know how to solve it  : (

could anybody help me ..

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

just take commit for this question

before I make a mistake that set wrong iptabes rules, and then I resolve it by below method, it works.

```
#1. first I inspect status and remove ipesec server, it conflicts.
sudo service ipsec status
sudo apt remove ipsec xl2tpd

#2. then I look for port 1723 that judge whether it recive data package
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 1723

#3. finally I change rules by using iptabes clearly
sudo iptables -t nat -nL
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

#4. and save it
sudo iptables -t nat -S
sudo iptables-save -t nat

#5. modify content in file before.rules, confirm it as a daemon
sudo vi /etc/ufw/before.rules

# just like below this
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [73:5676]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6:1415]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:431]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

that's all..